# How to print a float via serial?

Tags: c, atmega

So far I am able to send strings, numbers etc via uart. The code below runs on an embedded device (atmega328p) and sends data to my laptop on which putty runs:

```
void main(void)
{
    /* Works fine */
    int16_t a = 132;
    char data[100] = {0};

    sprintf(data, "%"PRId16, a);
    libuart_send("a: ", strlen("a: "));  
    libuart_send(data, strlen(data)); //works fine

    /* Below doesn't work */
    double l_data = 132.34;
    char data[100] = {0};

    sprintf(data, "%f", l_data);
    libuart_send("f: ", strlen("f: "));  
    libuart_send(data, strlen(data)); //doesnt work
}

void libuart_send(void *p_data, int p_data_size)
{
    assert(p_data != NULL);
    assert(p_data_size > 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < p_data_size; i++)
    {
        /* Wait for empty transmit buffer. */
        while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );

        /* Put data into buffer, sends the data. */
        UDR0 = *(((signed char*)(p_data)) + i);
    }
}
```

When sending the float to my putty terminal I see a question mark instead of the actual float value. Why?

Thanks

EDIT: This is a pdf version of the datasheet which explains what inter alia UDR0 does (see page 195/452): https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf

Comment: We don't know what `libuart_send` is doing (what is `UDR0` ?). You should provide us with some [MCVE]. Notice that per C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) `main` should return an `int`. So your code is not written in standard, hosted, C11 (and it should not even compile).

Comment: Perhaps your embedded device doesn't support passing a `float` to `sprintf`? Perhaps it requires you to link a floating point support library for that to work. Check your platform documentation.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch see update

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I already linked against -lprintf_flt , but that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVR port does not link any float support by default (BTW many ARM implementations also) because of the size of the functions. Remember that float math support + printf floats may take up to 15k of your 32k program memory!!

you need to add the correct options to print float numbers.

`-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm` and it will print.

BTW try to avoid floats as a plaque. Below you have the table with multiplication operation benchmark (results in cycles)

> uint8 22
>
> uint16 98
>
> uint32 102
>
> int8 22
>
> int16  92
>
> int32 108
>
> **float 2986**

on 1MHz you can only perform 300 float multiplications per second comparing to 10000 int32. Have it always in your maind

Comment: Why does this take so much more space?

Comment: because it is very complicated function.